# how to copy a masked password to another textbox and convert it to text

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I'm kinda new at this, I was just wondering if this is possible to do.

I have two textboxes in which the first textbox's texts is set to bullet, while the other one is plain text. I have checkbox too, so i can switch them whenever i want to reveal the password or not.

The question is, how can I copy the masked password from a textbox to the other textbox and convert it to plain and vice versa?

Comment: `PasswordBox.Password` stores the plain text password. Just set the `Text` property of the regular textbox to that.

Comment: you are talking about Winform, not WPF.

Comment: @kennyzx, I am talking about wpf... I am using it right now... i made the first textbox to view the keypress for a second and then changes to bullet.. but now i cannot copy the text in masked password textbox to the plaintext textbox

Comment: @Matt Burland, they are both plain textboxes.. not PasswordBox...

Comment: WPF's [TextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx) doesnot have that `passwordchar` property, unless you are embedding a [WinForm TextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.passwordchar(v=vs.110).aspx) in your WPF window.

Comment: @kennyzx, no.. okay nvm that passwordchar.. i just got mixed up... sorry if i were not that pro to notice.. My point is that the first textbox is in BULLET and the other is in plain text..

Comment: Why are you using a plain textbox instead of a passwordbox for the masked input?

Comment: @CodesInChaos, coz I programmatically masked the password so I can view the password later on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a way to do that is to have always the same text in the two textboxes.
when the user digits something in the first one, the second one changes aswell.

something like:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfStaff.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid >
    <TextBox Name="txt1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="122,123,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="165" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" />
    <TextBox Name="txt2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="122,163,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="165"  />
</Grid>
```

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfStaff
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            txt2.Text = txt1.Text;
        }

        private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(txt2!= null)
                txt2.Text = (sender as TextBox).Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried it and it worked, it copied what i typed in my first textbox, but the problem is i programmatically masked the password but 1 second to view the key pressed and turn it to bullet.. Now when this code is used, it just copied the bullets too.. how can i make this possible to view and store it to database?